# Parser Error - at the time of page laod

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am getting the  below error message after form loading  ..
may i know what is the problem..
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**-

Parser Error:

Desc: An error occured  during the parsing of a resource  required  to service  this request  the following  specific  parse error  details  and modify  your source  file approapriately.

Parser error Message: Only Content  controls are allowed  directly  in a contetnt page that contain  content  controls.

source error:

Line 245 
line 247 
Line 248

Comment: Could you explain when you get this error

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265119/only-content-controls-are-allowed-directly-in-a-content-page-that-contains-conte

Comment: after pressing the menu  i am loading the form  ok..

Comment: but out of 20  forms  one form is not loading it is giving the above error may i know how can i solve this one.. if you need any explanation ask me i will explain..

Comment: Hi any information plz i am waiting for your reply..